# How to save the selected image in UIImagePicker controller?

Tags: ios, camera

I can take a photo and it shows in imageviewn  but as soon as I leave detailviewn and go to back to detailviewn its disappear. How should the image always be saved?

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


}



- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: Save the image to the docs directory and reload it when you go back on the view...?

Comment: did you wrote image view code in view will appear method?

Answer (score 0):

Check your IBOutlet Connection  in xib file and You have to save the image taken in documents directory of your application , unless you cannot view the selected image